# What is the best way to limit number of features in TF-IDF?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-extraction, tfidf

I am using the tf-idf to build representations. It is large dataset and it quickly becomes too much for my RAM if I convert the matrix to a Data-Frame.

What is the best way to reduce the number of features/columns and retain the highest possible level of information.

The model has the possibility of setting max_features to a number but that retains features that have high_term frequency, which kind off defeats the purpose of tf-idf. You can also set stop-words, but that doesn't reduce the dimensionality much in my case.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to convert it to DataFrame as opposed to keeping sparse representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking the correct representation on `td-idf` encoding is a hyperparameter to be optimized.

As suggested in the above's answers, you can go for the regularization parameter i.e `min_df` which will control the minimum representativeness of a term to appear in the term-document matrix.

A reasonable approach would be a combination of both `min_df` and `ngram_range` but again via hyperparameter using cv score to select the appropriate one and of course, it is highly recommended to preprocess/clean the data by removing stopwords.

Answer (score 2):

You should almost always use the `min_df` parameter (minimum frequency) in order to limit the size of the vocabulary because:

- Rare words don't help the model and they often cause overfitting.
- Thanks to Zipf's law, this reduces the vocabulary size drastically much more than `max_df` or stop words. Therefore better model and lower memory requirement.